# Openshift Keycloak Restrict Admin Console

Tags: keycloak, openshift

I am currently using Keycloak version 21.0.2 on Openshift, and my admin console is accessible to the whole LAN. I was wondering how to restrict public access to the admin console (**https://keycloak_domain/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth**). If there is a solution that does not rely on IP addresses, it would be preferred, as all systems in a LAN share the same IP in openshift.